# Modules and Diagonizability using Primary Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, diagonalization, primary-decomposition

Given a field $K$, a vector space $V$ over $K$ and a linear map $T:V \longrightarrow V$  of finite dimension with minimal polynomial $\mu(x)\in K[X]$, prove using the primary decomposition of V (modules) that $\mu$ factors completely as a product of different monic linear polynomials if, and only if, $T$ is diagonalizable.

I have tried using linear algebra techniques but primary decomposition results problematic. Any hint will be more than welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Turn $V$ into a $K[X]$-module via $T$.

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit more I would appreciate and could pick close the thread

Comment: What kind of primary decomposition are you refering to?